# Error in windows forms

Tags: c#

First of all, sorry for my bad english,

My teacher gave me some homeworks to do, he told me to make a program with 'windows forms' to order fruits from home, but i have these two errors in the code. These two errors are coming from the rows with three slashes. I hope somebody can help me with this. Thank you.

```
        this.tex_shbanane.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 242);
        this.tex_shbanane.Name = "tex_shbanane";
        this.tex_shbanane.ReadOnly = true;
        this.tex_shbanane.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        this.tex_shbanane.TabIndex = 22;
 ///    this.tex_shbanane.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tex_shbanane_TextChanged);
        // 
        // tex_shgjithsej
        // 
        this.tex_shgjithsej.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 268);
        this.tex_shgjithsej.Name = "tex_shgjithsej";
        this.tex_shgjithsej.ReadOnly = true;
        this.tex_shgjithsej.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        this.tex_shgjithsej.TabIndex = 23;
        this.tex_shgjithsej.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tex_shgjithsej_TextChanged);
        // 
        // tex_shtaksa
        // 
        this.tex_shtaksa.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 294);
        this.tex_shtaksa.Name = "tex_shtaksa";
        this.tex_shtaksa.ReadOnly = true;
        this.tex_shtaksa.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        this.tex_shtaksa.TabIndex = 24;
        this.tex_shtaksa.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tex_shtaksa_TextChanged);
        // 
        // tex_shtransporti
        // 
        this.tex_shtransporti.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 318);
        this.tex_shtransporti.Name = "tex_shtransporti";
        this.tex_shtransporti.ReadOnly = true;
        this.tex_shtransporti.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        this.tex_shtransporti.TabIndex = 25;
    /// this.tex_shtransporti.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tex_shtransporti_TextChanged);
```

Comment: ..what are the errors?

Comment: which type of error ?

Comment: CS1061 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'tex_shtransporti_TextChanged' and no extension method 'tex_shtransporti_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: The error message is quite clear; you are using a method `tex_shtransporti_TextChanged` you have never defined. You need to define it. One way of doing that is opening the Design view, clicking your `tex_` fields, clicking the Event panel (it has a lightning bolt icon), clicking the TextChanged event and selecting `tex_shtransporti_TextChanged`. If one isn't there, double-click the event and it will open a blank definition.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already understood why are you getting error from @Dour's comment.

You have not defined the event `tex_shtransporti_TextChanged`.

```
    private void tex_shtransporti_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // implement your code here. 
    }
```

Just note also you can manually generate event also from VS designer.Just follow the steps.

- Click on the TextBox inside your form.
- Open the properties windows
  (press F4).
- Select the event page.
- Double click on the TextChanged
  property line.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now.